# PHP Mail, CC Field

Tags: php, email

How can I include a CC field in this function?

```
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) {
    $file = $path.$filename;
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $name = basename($file);
    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";
    if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
        echo  "OK"; // or use booleans here
    } else {
        echo  "ERROR!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Either one of the answers will do...have you considered using a library (phpmailer, swiftmailer, pear::mail, etc...) to make your life easier?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Add this while declaring headers:

```
$headers .= 'Cc: somebody@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 20):

Add `$header .= "CC: ".$cc."\r\n";` after the `Reply-To`-line.

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_mail_mail.asp

Answer (score 9):

Please don't build your own MIME emails. Use something like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) instead. Far easier to use and less brittle. Adding a CC with that is as simple as:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->AddCC('somebody@example.com');
```