# PHP insert cc into mail function

Tags: php, email, header, carbon-copy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Mail, CC Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582126/php-mail-cc-field)

I am using the following php to send an email.  I need to add cc to my email.  When I try to insert into header the html message show the raw html.  What is the best way to handle a cc?

Thanks

```
$headers = "From: $from_email\r\nReply-To: $from_email";

$headers .= "Return-Path: <info@premierinspectiontn.com>";

//add boundary string and mime type specification
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

just tested this, and it worked as expected:

```
$headers .= 'Cc: test@test.com\r\n';
$headers .= 'Bcc: test@test.com\r\n';
```

I would also suggest moving your carriage return and new line to the end of the previous entry to `$headers`

```
$headers = "From: $from_email\r\nReply-To: $from_email";
$headers .= 'Cc: test@test.com\r\n';
$headers .= 'Bcc: test@test.com\r\n';
$headers .= "Return-Path: <info@premierinspectiontn.com>\r\n";

// add boundary string and mime type specification
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";
```

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tested your code and the email message body worked but the cc didn't get sent.  Any ideas what could be the cause?

Comment: If you look at the raw header information, do you see the cc there? Would it be possible to post the headers?

Comment: I decided to start the page from scratch redo the page and took off the cc and this is the email message: <br/>  --PHP-alt-0603545d439904956b8f20136436ede1 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello World!!! 
This is simple text email message. 

--PHP-alt-0603545d439904956b8f20136436ede1 
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<p>This is something with <b>HTML</b> formatting.</p> 

--PHP-alt-0603545d439904956b8f20136436ede1--

Comment: CC did not work for me either

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
$headers .= 'CC: other@url.com' . "\r\n";
```