# how to send email to client and one one copy to me with html form

Tags: php, email

I want to send an email without tml form when a user has finished filling in an HTML form and then emailing information from the form. I want to do it from the same script that displays the web page that has the form.

Comment: If you want to add something to your question, please do so by editing the question, not by a comment. It is very difficult to read if the information is spread across multiple posts.

Answer (score 2):

May be it's help you see this [StackAnswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040866/php-insert-cc-into-mail-function)

just add cc and bcc in your mail function header.

Try This code :-

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $to = "*********@gmail.com";

    $from = "client@email.com"; 

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From: $from_email\r\nReply-To: $from_email";
    $headers .= 'Cc:'.$yourmail.'\r\n';

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
   }
?>
```

Comment: here in my email emai session $vemail = $_SESSION["b"]; which i need to pass here:$from = $_POST['email'];

Comment: which email you get in $vemail your email or client email?

Comment: i want  client email

Comment: you write in detail what you want so we understand properly and help you perfectly....

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $to = "********@gmail.com"; 
        $from = email@mail.com; 
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; 
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $subject = "Form submission"; 
        $subject2 = ""; 
        $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message']; 
        $message2 = " " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message']; $headers = "From:" . $from; 
        $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); 
        mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: please elaborate the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can add CC in your email code `headers`

```
$headers .= 'Cc: yourmail@domain.net' . "\r\n";
```

So your email would be added to cc so whatever mail is send to user also a copy of that mail is send to you