# How to add a cc in a php contact form?

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I have a contact form for a HTML page. Right now the recipient is only one. How can I add multiple recipient. Any help on this would be a great help.

Code is below.

Thanks.

```
<?php

$to = "support@domain.in";

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$subject = "Message from $name ($email)";
$replyto = $email;

$headers="";
$headers = "From: test <domain@one.com>\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $replyto";

$result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

?>

Comment: $headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n"; You can make list of emails

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Mail, CC Field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582126/php-mail-cc-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your sample code

```
     $to = "xyz@somedomain.com";
     $subject = "This is subject";

     $message = "<b>This is HTML message.</b>";
     $message .= "<h1>This is headline.</h1>";

     $header = "From:abc@somedomain.com \r\n";
     $header .= "Cc:afgh@somedomain.com \r\n";
     $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
     $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

     $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);

     if( $retval == true ) {
        echo "Message sent successfully...";
     }else {
        echo "Message could not be sent...";
     }
```

Comment: Thank You Bikash Paul. I will try it.